# Как исправить отображение элементов flexbox в ie11?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Добрый день. Не могу понять, почему в **IE11** блок **.main** работает не корректно!

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    min-height: 100vh;

    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;

    -webkit-flex-flow: column wrap;
    -ms-flex-flow: column wrap;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
}

.header {
    -ms-flexbox: 0 0 auto;
    -webkit-flex: 0 0 auto;
    flex: 0 0 auto;

    height: 200px;
    background: #777;
}

.main {
    -webkit-flex: 1;
    -ms-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;

    background: red;
}

.footer {
    -webkit-flex: 0 0 auto;
    -ms-flex: 0 0 auto;
    flex: 0 0 auto;

    height: 200px;
    background: #777;
}
```

```html
<header class="header"></header>
<main class="main"></main>
<footer class="footer"></footer>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/un68kwwo/1/ - везде он работает хорошо, но в **IE11** косяк, хотя у него поддержка flexbox очень даже хорошая.

Comment: потому-что тэг main не поддерживается IE http://htmlbook.ru/html/main

Comment: Хм. Ужас какой-то, но это не решает проблему, даже если в примере изменить main на div

Answer (score 1):

Пробуем вот так:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box; 
}

html, body {
    height: 100vh; //В IE работает только с 100vh, с min-height - не работает
}
body {
    display: flex;
 flex-direction: column; 
}

.header {    
    height: 200px;
    background: #777;
}

.main {    
    width: 100%;
    flex-grow: 1;
    background: red;
    padding: 20px; //Обязательно задаем хоть какой-то размер (здесь добавлен паддинг, чтобы в примере было видно, что .main отображается)
}

.footer {      
    height: 200px;
    background: #777;
}
```

```html
<div class="header"></div>
  <div class="main">
   Lorem ipsum
  </div>
  <div class="footer"></div>
```